# Bash function to run arbitrary command on two branches

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to write a bash function that executes an arbitrary commands on multiple branches.

```
compare_command () {
    branch2="$1"
    shift
    command="$@"
    echo $branch2
    echo $command
    # assume $@ is command and args
    $(command) 2>&1 | tee baseline.log
    git checkout "$branch2"
    $(command) 2>&1 | tee "$branch2".log
    git checkout -
}
```

`compare_command master ls`, for example, fails with "command not found: 1"
`compare_command master ls -a`, fails with "command not found: ls -a"

Comment: Going by the output you say you get, that's not the function you're actually running.

Comment: You can't expect to be able to assign the list `"$@"` to a string and then use it as a command. Also, `$(command)` runs the `command` built-in command and nothing else.  As muru says, you don't appear to be running the code you are showing.

Comment: Is there a way to assign the command to one variable and all args to another variable and then `$(command "$args") ` or some such?

Comment: Use an array, not a string variable. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946  Consider showing us the actual code that you run though.

Comment: Your question is not clear: What do you mean by branches? What type of branches? **Tell us what you are trying to achieve**, then show what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are just confused how brackets are used in bash

```
compare_command () {
    branch2="$1"
    shift
    echo "$branch2"
    echo "$@"
    # assume $@ is command and args
    "$@" 2>&1 | tee baseline.log
    git checkout "$branch2"
    "$@" 2>&1 | tee "$branch2".log
    git checkout -
}
```